# Html/php: how to include a php file when only a tab is clicked using php & html only?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

What I'm trying to do is including multiple php files in my page put I want to load php files only when I click the related tab

I tried 2 different ways to get it working but it didn't

in first case it always load all included files at page's load put it doesn't show files unless I click related tab

here is my code:

```
  <?php 
   if(isset($_POST['tab'])){
      $tab = $_POST['tab'];
   } else{
      $tab = 'Dashboard';
   }
  ?>
<div class="tabs">
    <div id="Dashboard" class="tab">
        <?php include('dashboard.php'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Members" class="tab">
        <?php include('accounts.php');} ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Export" class="tab">
        <?php include('export.php'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<aside id="sidebar">
    <strong class="logo"><a href="#">lg</a></strong>
    <ul class="tabset buttons">
        <li <?php if($tab == 'Dashboard'){ echo 'class="active"'; } else $_POST['tab']='Dashboard';?>>
            <a href="#Dashboard" class="ico1"><span>Dashboard</span><em></em></a>
        </li>
        <li <?php if($tab == 'Members'){ echo 'class="active"'; } else $_POST['tab']='Members';?>>
            <a href="#Members" class="ico2"><span>Members</span><em></em></a>
        </li>
        <li <?php if($tab == 'Export'){ echo 'class="active"'; } else $_POST['tab']='Export';?>>
            <a href="#Export" class="ico3"><span>Export</span><em></em></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

and with this code it loads only dashboard.php file

```
  <?php 
   if(isset($_POST['tab'])){
      $tab = $_POST['tab'];
   } else{
      $tab = 'Dashboard';
   }
  ?>
<div class="tabs">
    <div id="Dashboard" class="tab">
        <?php if($tab == 'Dashboard'){include('dashboard.php');} ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Members" class="tab">
        <?php if($tab == 'Members'){include('accounts.php');} ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Export" class="tab">
        <?php if($tab == 'Export'){include('export.php');} ?>
    </div>
</div>
<aside id="sidebar">
    <strong class="logo"><a href="#">lg</a></strong>
    <ul class="tabset buttons">
        <li <?php if($tab == 'Dashboard'){ echo 'class="active"'; } else $tab = $_POST['tab']='Dashboard';?>>
            <a href="#Dashboard" class="ico1"><span>Dashboard</span><em></em></a>
        </li>
        <li <?php if($tab == 'Members'){ echo 'class="active"'; } else $tab = $_POST['tab']='Members';?>>
            <a href="#Members" class="ico2"><span>Members</span><em></em></a>
        </li>
        <li <?php if($tab == 'Export'){ echo 'class="active"'; } else $tab = $_POST['tab']='Export';?>>
            <a href="#Export" class="ico3"><span>Export</span><em></em></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

I don't have any knowledge with Ajax or jQuery so is it possible to do only with php and html?

and sorry for my poor English

Comment: It's not possible in this way. PHP is server side, html is client side.
Use ajax for it.
When you click on tab, your javascript code send request with AJAX to the server side php script.
In php script you get parameters and according to them, returns to the client side the needed html.

Comment: @MichaelVaysman I don't have any experience with ajax. Can you point me to a tutorial that solves my problem? thank you

Comment: Afaics, you only have 2 options. Either a) make those links into actual links that take them to URLs that allow you to define what the page is to display and include or b) use JS and AJAX.

Comment: @Mohammad here you are: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use GET parameters, if you dont want to use AJAX in this example. But I am not sure about what you are planning.

```php
<?php 
 if(isset($_GET['tab'])){
    $tab = $_GET['tab'];
 } else{
    $tab = 'Dashboard';
 }
?>
<div class="tabs">
    <div id="Dashboard" class="tab">
        <?php if($tab == 'Dashboard'){include('dashboard.php');} ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Members" class="tab">
        <?php if($tab == 'Members'){include('accounts.php');} ?>
    </div>
    <div id="Export" class="tab">
        <?php if($tab == 'Export'){include('export.php');} ?>
    </div>
</div>
<aside id="sidebar">
    <strong class="logo"><a href="#">lg</a></strong>
    <ul class="tabset buttons">
        <li <?php if($tab == 'Dashboard'){ echo 'class="active"'; }?>>
            <a href="?tab=Dashboard" class="ico1"><span>Dashboard</span><em></em></a>
        </li>
        <li <?php if($tab == 'Members'){ echo 'class="active"'; }?>>
            <a href="?tab=Members" class="ico2"><span>Members</span><em></em></a>
        </li>
        <li <?php if($tab == 'Export'){ echo 'class="active"'; }?>>
            <a href="?tab=Export" class="ico3"><span>Export</span><em></em></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me don't know why. which link do you mean?

Comment: I published the complete [code on GitHub](https://github.com/ppalmtag/stackoverflow_33395057) for you to check. I meant that link `code´<a href="?tab=Export" class="ico3">`.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and sorry for late :)